# why does py iterate dict keys fail to print keys?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm new to py and ran into an unexpected behavior :

```
tracker = Dict[int, List[int]]      
tracker.update({1: {1,2,3}})
tracker.update({2: {4,5,6}})
tracker.update({3: {7,8,9}})
for key in tracker:
  print(key)
```

stdout:

```
*typing.Dict[int, typing.List[int]]
```

I was expecting this output :

```
1
2
3
```

Can someone explain this behavior, and also describe how to iterate and print the dict keys ?

Comment: You've assigned the ***Type Definition*** to `tracker`, not an actual instance of a dictionary. Try `tracker: Dict[int, List[int]] = dict()`

Comment: Also `{1,2,3}` is a set, not a list.

Comment: What do the `.update` lines even mean in this case?

Comment: Ah ok thanks, the way I've defined it, `tracker` is a type and `print(key)` somehow outputs that type.

Also, what is the correct way to add `List[int]` to a `dict` ?

Comment: @BaltoStar Why do so many of your questions have no accepted answer?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Apparently, `tracker.update()` is the unbounded `dict.update()` which may be called with only one argument for `self`, in which case it just does nothing.

Comment: Please don't use `update` to assign just one item! Instead of `tracker.update({1: {1,2,3}})` use `tracker[1] = {1,2,3}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've assigned the ***Type Definition*** to `tracker`, not an actual instance of a dictionary.

Also `{1,2,3}` is a set, not a list.

```
tracker: Dict[int, List[int]] = dict()
    
tracker.update({1: [1,2,3]})
tracker.update({2: [4,5,6]})
tracker.update({3: [7,8,9]})

for key in tracker.keys():
  print(key)
```

Or...

```
tracker: Dict[int, List[int]] = dict()
    
tracker[1] = [1,2,3]
tracker[2] = [4,5,6]
tracker[3] = [7,8,9]

for key in tracker.keys():
  print(key)
```

Or...

```
tracker: Dict[int, List[int]] = {
   1: [1,2,3], 
   2: [4,5,6], 
   3: [7,8,9], 
}

for key in tracker.keys():
  print(key)
```